# Simplify API calls when using pipe and HttpService in Angular8

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpservice

In most of my API calls I use this pattern:

1. call server and pipe result
2. Check for error and throw if needed
3. map results from server

   public getItems() : Observable<Item[]> {

   ```
     return this.http.get<Item[]>>(environment.url + '/items').pipe(

            catchError((error:any)=> throwError('Failed getting items')),

            map((ret)=> this.mapResults(ret)));
   ```

   }

Is there a way to merge the catchError and map operators to a single operator ?

Something like this:

```
catchErrorAndMap("Message in case of error",itemForMapping)
```

itemForMapping will go into the mapping function. something like this?

```
 return this.http.get<Item[]>>(environment.url + '/items').pipe(
    
                catchErrorAndMap('Failed getting items'),ret));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. An RxJS operator is just a function. So, you can write your own RxJS operators.

There is an example here: https://netbasal.com/creating-custom-operators-in-rxjs-32f052d69457

In the section entitled: "Creating Operators from Existing Operators".

So you can create a `catchErrorAndMap` function that you can then use as an operator.

Here is an example:

```
export function catchErrorAndMap(errorMessage): OperatorFunction<User[], User[]> {
  return source =>
    source.pipe(
      catchError((error: any) => throwError(errorMessage)),
      map(items => items.map(item => ({ ...item, name: item.name + "'s"} as User)))
    );
}
```

This creates a function that takes in an Observable<User[]> and returns an Observable<User[]>. You'd need to modify it as needed for your project. (Probably Item[]).

It then pipes the source (which is the emitted item from the source stream) through the desired operators.

In this example, I used a map operation appropriate for my data. You could of course change it to your `this.mapResults()`.

You'd call this operator just like any other pipe operator:

```
  users$ = this.http
    .get<User[]>(this.userUrl)
    .pipe(catchErrorAndMap("Error Occurred"));
```

Comment: event when creating my own operator i will have to catch error before?   .pipe(
              catchError((error:any)=> throwError('Failed getting available product importers')),
              catchErrorAndMap()
        )

Comment: I added a more specific example to my post.